# Convert bag file to a common pointcloud format

Tags: ros, point-cloud-library, rosbag

OS: Ubuntu 18.04

Lidar: Livox Mid 40

Hello,

im using livox mid 40 which export point cloud to .lvx files or rosbags. I am looking for a way to convert these files to a common pointcloud format like ply, las, laz so i can use it to programs like cloudcompare, meshlab or other. I tried some solutions like **rosrun pcl_ros bag_to_pcd <input_file.bag>  <output_directory>** or cloud_assembler but the first one creates multiple pcds and not a single point cloud (it created one pcd for each frame) and the second one doesn't work ([cloud_assembler_try](https://answers.ros.org/question/383103/ros-laser_assembler/)).

Im really confused!!

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: As for pcl_ros bag_to_pcd, a bag file is a frame-by-frame recording of a lidar run. Don't you want that? If you want just one lidar msg / frame, then filter just that frame. If you want to merge frames, that's a separate issue, but can be done with pcl as well. So, in general, I still think your best solution, unless the manufacturer has more software, is to leverage the rosbag files, since there's many converters from ros/pcl PointCloud2 msgs to any other pointcloud format.

Comment: Hello my friend and thanks for the response. I was wondering if i can save or convert rosbag to a common file format like las,laz,ply. I dont want multiple pcd files for every frame but a single pointcloud so i can import it in any pointcloud program like cloudcompare etc.

Comment: There should only be 1 file per frame; 1 file per pointcloud message recorded. If you want to select just one & convert it, or if you want to merge a few together into one, either way would work. But if you record a bunch of pointclouds, it's up to you to pick (or merge) the one you want.